# Can't access Google, Wikipedia on multiple browsers?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I am having a weird problem. yesterday Google, Wikipedia and Yahoo worked fine in my PC.. but today all of a sudden i get the

> Server not found Firefox can't find
>   the server at www.google.com.

I am not behind any firewall.

I did a malware scan - Still didn't work
I checked the host file - Still didn't work
I tried in wireless/wired with my laptop - Still didn't work

at last i formatted my PC and reinstalled windows XP but i still get the "Server not found".

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Did you try with another web browser?

Comment: is it just those three sites or all sites?

Comment: @Mr. Man i tried FF, IE and Chrome... @Xantec: so far those are the sites. most of the others work fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you change your Primary and Secondary DNS to OpenDNS servers and check if you can access those sites?

These are the the settings

```
208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220
```

There is a possibility that your ISP's DNS servers have some issues. You should give them a call and double check.

If you don't know how to change you DNS settings [click here](http://kawaiimiyuki.wordpress.com/2008/03/27/tutorials-for-dummies-27032008-how-to-change-your-lan-ip-address/).

Comment: Cool.. Thank you very much... Everything is working fine now..

Comment: @LiveEn: Sweet! Happy browsing! and don't forget to give your ISP's tech-support a call.

Comment: Sure.. i will ;)

Comment: It's easier to memorize Google's Public DNS servers: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. Heck, I haven't forgotten those since I looked at them.